# sscanf with less arguments than specified?

Tags: c, cstring, scanf, c-strings

So I'm wondering how sscanf functions when faced with a line like this:

```
sscanf(input_string, "%s %s %s", cmd1, cmd2, cmd3);
```

But say the input_string only contains 1 string token. What values are assigned to cmd2 and cmd3? Is there an error thrown?

I'm using the GNU C compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing will be assigned to the extra parameters. The return from `sscanf` tells you how many conversions were done successfully, so in this case it would return `1`. You typically just compare to the number you expect, and assume the input is bad otherwise:

```
if (3 != sscanf(input_string,"%s %s %s", cmd1, cmd2, cmd3))
    fprintf(stderr, "Badly formatted input (expecting three strings)\n");
```

When you're reading from a file, you often want to execute in a loop until you get correct input:

```
while (3 != scanf("%s %s %s", cmd1, cmd2, cmd3))
    fprintf(stderr, "Please enter 3 strings:");
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sscanf/

> On success, the function returns the number of items in the argument
>   list successfully filled. This count can match the expected number of
>   items or be less -even zero- in the case of a matching failure. In the
>   case of an input failure before any data could be successfully
>   interpreted, EOF is returned.